# Content Security Policy "data" not working for base64 Images in Chrome 28

Tags: content-security-policy

In this simple example, I'm trying to set a CSP header with the meta http-equiv header. I included a base64 image and I'm trying to make Chrome load the image.

I thought the `data` keyword should do that,
but somehow it's not working.

I just get the following error in Developer Tools:

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAOZEAMkJCfAwMMYGBtZMTP75+euIiPFBP+hVVf3v7…nw7yk4Mjr6GLUY+joiBI2QAACABwJDCHgoKOHEoAYVBAgY8GGAxAoNGAmiwMHBCgccKDAKBAA7' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data".

The example code (JSFiddle is not working for this example because I cannot set meta header there):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'none';
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        img-src 'self' data;
        " />
    <style>
        #helloCSP {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CSP</h1>
    <div id="helloCSP"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also open this example here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/638360/ps/csp.html

Comment: If you're still looking after a solution, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213224/7827321

Answer (score 813, accepted):

According to [the grammar in the CSP spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#framework-directive-source-list), you need to specify schemes as `scheme:`, not just `scheme`. So, you need to change the image source directive to:

```
img-src 'self' data:;
```

Comment: The reason for this awkwardness is that it's otherwise difficult to distinguish between the 'data' scheme, and a host named 'data'.

Comment: I think URLs are a bit awkward to parse in general.

Comment: I had my data: in quotes  - 'data:' - that also fails to work - and your answer also alerted me to that as a problem

Comment: It's useful to note that you shouldn't just add this without considering the security implications. See [this security stack exchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/95011/7090)

Comment: Security scanners find data: as insecure element

Comment: A problem we've run into (with not adding the insecure `data:`), is that html5 `video` elements trip the CSP when it tries to add a data:image/svg of like the pause icon, and play icons etc (nothing we have on our end, its entirely the browser doing it). Its random, and may be a Chrome issue, but its annoying like hell.

Comment: I'd really like to see an example showcasing that using `img-src data:` has security implications.

Comment: In my case - "connect-src 'self' data: - seems to work

Comment: @MatthijsWessels @Abdull my understanding is that `img-src data:` would not introduce a cross-site-scripting vulnerability, since a script in an img tag won't run. Allowing data urls for `default-src` or other would be risky tho.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I needed to include also "data:" to the "default-src 'self'" element:

```
default-src 'self'; ... -> default-src 'self' data:; ...
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

data to load:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'><path fill='#343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/></svg>
```

get a utf8 to base64 convertor and convert the "svg" string to:

```
PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHZpZXdCb3g9JzAgMCA0IDUn
PjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9JyMzNDNhNDAnIGQ9J00yIDBMMCAyaDR6bTAgNUwwIDNoNHonLz48L3N2Zz4=
```

and the CSP is

```
img-src data: image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHZpZXdCb3g9JzAgMCA0IDUn
PjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9JyMzNDNhNDAnIGQ9J00yIDBMMCAyaDR6bTAgNUwwIDNoNHonLz48L3N2Zz4=
```

Comment: I don't think its possible to include a type after the protocol. Only "data:" is valid.