# What is the maximally permissive Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: content-security-policy

I have a large, legacy codebase that I'd like to introduce the `Content-Security-Policy` header on. It is not feasible in the short term to truly lock-down the site (for example, there are inline scripts all over the place that have no automated test coverage), but at least I can start by forbidding access to content sources that I know for sure aren't in use currently and then slowly ratchet it down over time.

Unfortunately, the list of sources that aren't being used is rather short. This was my first attempt at a `Content-Security-Policy` value:

```
default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'
```

That broke a number of things, such as [images sourced using the data: scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18447970/27581). Looking around, I see [a number of things you might want to include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280371/27581), such as `connect-src ws:`, that aren't explicitly called out in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives).

What is the maximally permissive `Content-Security-Policy` header value that basically lets the site do everything the browser is allowed to do by default? Asked another way: **what header value can I introduce that definitely won't break anything on the site?**

I'd feel more comfortable introducing the header into the legacy site if I could start with something that I know won't break anything, then subtract out the permissions that I know are safe to remove.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**tl;dr use "report only" mode to introduce a policy to a legacy site.**

See w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-guid-matching.

> As defined above, special URL schemes that refer to specific pieces
>   of unique content, such as "data:", "blob:" and "filesystem:" are
>   excluded from matching a policy of * and must be explicitly listed.

Therefor, something along the lines of `default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-dynamic' data: filesystem: about: blob: ws: wss:` is probably close to the most lenient policy. There are more protocols that may need to be whitelisted, of course.

---

HOWEVER

Typically people take the opposite approach. They will deploy the header with `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none'` which will not affect the loading of your site and will allow you to ratchet down your policy based on the violations or console warnings.

I highly recommend you start with the [caspr chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caspr-enforcer/fekcdjkhlbjngkimekikebfegbijjafd?hl=en-US) to create an initial policy and then use report-uri.io to view report violations. When your policy seems stable and violations are minimal, then switch your policy to enforce mode.

Comment: Cool. I particularly appreciate that you both answered the question as asked and pointed out a probably better way to do it (caspr extension and using reporting mode, which I had overlooked). I'm going to try it out.

Comment: This still gives me an `Refused to load the image` error :)

Comment: @hugoderhungrige if you provide the full error message I assure you we can update this. Without that information, it's impossible to guess what happened.

Comment: @oreoshake my bad. The error was related to some proxy configuration, not the CSP.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-dynamic'; 
script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
frame-src *; 
style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
```

Even with this, you might still find violations, if you find them, report it to me!

Comment: @AliGhasemzadeh can you be more specific, what is the error message? How it doesn't work?

Comment: instead of asking to report, just use `report-uri` directive

Comment: Do you really need to set all `*-src` directives other than `default-src` ? The spec for CSP says that all other `*-src` directives will ultimately fall back to `default-src`.

Comment: @pepoluan this was ages ago but the reason was that Chrome didn't respect this behavior, I hope it is better nowadays, try it and find out!

Comment: @Rainb we tested, seems the behavior have been fixed on recent Chrome. Thanks!