# Refused to load the font - Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

I am starting on Angular 2 and have been playing around with routes.
Everything was working correctly when I did not have routes, but now every time I go to /home, I get this error.

```
Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAIw4ABEAAAABQcAAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…hgZiCKVViwAiVhsAFFYyNisAIjRLMJCgMCK7MLEAMCK7MRFgMCK1myBCgGRVJEswsQBAIrAA==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I am working with HAML but I don't think that is the problem.
Index is still .html extension which also doesn't seem to be causing problems.

Here is my index.html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Freelance Bootcamp</title>
    <base href='/'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <app>App Loading...</app>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomepageComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.haml'
})
export class AppComponent {
    title: 'Freelance Bootcamp Dashboard';
}
```

homepage.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'homepage',
    templateUrl: 'homepage.component.haml'
})
export class HomepageComponent {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent },
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The redirectTo /home works when I go to localhost:4200.
If I go to localhost:4200/home, that's when I get the error described and my page gets stuck in the App Loading... screen.

If it helps, I generated the application with angular-cli by typing:

```
ng new application
```

If anyone could help me with this, that would be amazing and thank you in advance.

I hope this is enough information to go off of. If not, please let me know what else you need to know.

Comment: in angular cli might be some optin for font. not sure, but you can try

Answer (score 2):

Add a [content security policy](https://content-security-policy.com/).

E.g. `font-src` to use `data:`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' data:;">
```

And if you use CDNs, add as needed, e.g. for `fonts.gstatic.com`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com;">
```

Comment: not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198310/content-security-policy-directive-refused-to-load-the-font?noredirect=1#comment81345495_47198310

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461211/what-is-the-maximally-permissive-content-security-policy