# What is the default value of the Content Security Policy?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'd like to specify the Content-Security-Policy `meta` tag the `head` of in a web page with a value which will have the same effect as having no content security policy at all. What should it look like?

Comment: See also [What is the maximally permissive Content-Security-Policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461211/what-is-the-maximally-permissive-content-security-policy) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461211/what-is-the-maximally-permissive-content-security-policy

Comment: Also see [How does Content Security Policy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30280370/608639)