# create-react-app issue: Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I am attempting to deploy a react app to Heroku. I have a NodeJs/Express API and it is serving my app created with create-react-app.

I am trying to display images in an  tag from an external API (https://www.thecocktaildb.com) on my site and I continue to receive the following error in production:

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

I have tried to get around this using many variations of the following code snippet in my public/index.html file but nothing has worked so far.

```
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="img-src 'self' https://www.thecocktaildb.com data:;"
/>
```

I have run out of things to try and cannot find a solution anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360666/11624647

try add in your tag

```
img-src * 'self' data: https:
```

code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Comment: Sadly this did not work. I received ```Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".``` Could create-react-app be configuring this somewhere else?

Comment: ensure cors enabled in https://www.thecocktaildb.com  that particular website allowed to access third parties