# Content Security policy directive :"img-src 'self' data:" issue while loading image from url in angular 8 , nodejs as server

Tags: html, angular, content-security-policy

I tried different ways even using this url : [StackOverflow CSP Image issue](http://%3Chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360109/content-security-policy-img-src-self-data%3E)

But still facing the issue:

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violets the following Content Security Policy directive : image-src 'self' data:.
```

My URL looks like this:

```
https://abcstotrage.blob.core.windows.net/contnr/folderimg/img/2/2019_45_566_x.bmp?x=2019-12-14&sr=tyu
```

And I am using below metaTag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:; 
img-src https://* 'self' data: mediastream: blob: filesystem; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; 
style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Comment: Check if you also have a CSP response header that serves the directive you see in the error message.

Comment: @Halvor Sakshuag I am using nodejs as a server and it fetches the data from azure blob ,so do i need to add csp header in nodejs as well

Comment: Halvor Sakshaug meant that you have 2 different CSPs at the same time; one via HTTP header and second - via meta tag. Because we observe `image-src 'self' data:` in the error message but `mg-src https://* 'self' data: mediastream: blob: filesystem` in meta.