What is a secure Content-Security-Policy for matplotlib plots embedded in a flask app?
I have made a Flask app that will not display plots generated by matplotlib when I try to secure it for production.
To deploy this app I have been setting security headers.
When I set, response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "img-src 'self'", the plots generated by the app do not display.
What might be a content-security-policy that would allow images generated during the running of the Flask app?

Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360109/content-security-policy-img-src-self-data ?

You should check the console errors in the browser. Some possible reasons:

The images are not on the http(s) scheme, and you'll need to add "data:" or "blob:".
The images are served from a different, non-standard, port.
There are multiple policies, and content needs to pass all policies. There could be a default policy such as "default-src 'none'" that blocks everything (but this is less likely if it is just the images that are gone.

