Report Only: Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg > xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' when clicking on a Bootstrap 5 radio button
When clicking on the radio button below I'm getting this message on the console of my different web browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc).

[Report Only] Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle
r='2' fill='%23fff'/%3e%3c/svg%3e' because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that
'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
fallback.

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        Default radio
        </label>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>

I don't get the message if I remove the class form-check-input.

You need to add data: as a valid image source, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449556/1427878

When I ran your code on my machine it was working fine with no console. One of possible cause can be internet issue.
One more thing you can try is put <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> just above </body>.
Thank You.
